# WPF: Textbox width guidelines

Tags: wpf

Is there a formula for textbox widths as a multiple of max. characters?

I assume that if my textbox holds 40 characters, I should be able to plug it into a formula that looks like F(40) = (40 * X + Y).

Answer (score 2):

I think it really depends on the font you are using. I'm sorry for not giving you the formula, but you can find [FormattedText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.aspx) class helpful. Especially its [Width](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.formattedtext.width.aspx) property.

In case of fixed-width fonts it's as easy as measuring any character width with `FormattedText`, and multiplying it by number of characters. In other cases things get trickier...

Answer (score 0):

For the time being I'm using `width(n) = 11n+8`. This is based on the defaults for Windows 7 and the width of the M character.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, is this something that's used elsewhere? If so, could you share a URL? Thanks.

Comment: It is based purely on experimentation.